# Cocos2D-iPhone CGRectContainsPoint detecting touch outside sprite bounds

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Could someone please help me. I am trying to use a CCSprite as a movement controller that I can drag (Left/Right) to move my player character. Problem is when I touch outside the CCSprite it still detects as Active, which is an enum that I set ACTIVE on ccTouchBegan, and IDLE in ccTouchEnded methods. By default it is in IDLE state. Not sure why it is activating when I begin touch outside of my CCSprite.

Please advise.

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL touched = NO;

    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
    loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: loc];

    //avatar is a CCSprite...
    //inside of IF statement should not execute if I touch anywhere on screen 
    //outside of self.avatar sprite, but it still executes....
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint( [self.avatar boundingBox], loc) );
    {
        self.state = ACTIVE;
        self.action = MOVE_STOPPED; //player decides which direction to move, based on action state
        self.currPoint = self.prevPoint = self.avatar.position;
        touched = YES;
    }
    return touched;
}
```

Comment: is the sprite rotated? Cause the boundingBox is axis-aligned, ie it is larger than the sprite when rotated and largest when the sprite is rotated 45 (90+45, 180+45, 270+45) degrees.

Comment: No the sprite is not rotated. It is a 100 x 100 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone I was able to solve the issue. Instead of subclassing CCLayer, I subclassed CCNode. In my ccTouchBegan method, I did an explicit bound check to see if touch's location in convertToNodeSpace was inside sprite's boundingBox. I borrowed the explicit bound check from SneakyInput button class.

Here is the ccTouchBegan method. If anyone has any ideas of how to do this in subclass of CCLayer, please let me know so I don't have to implement my own CCTouchOneByOneDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL touched = NO;

    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
    loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: loc];
    loc = [self.avatar convertToNodeSpace: loc]; //YvesLeBorg's feedback

    float width = [self.avatar boundingBox].size.width;
    float height = [self.avatar boundingBox].size.height;
    //if ( CGRectContainsPoint( [self.avatar boundingBox], loc) );
    if ( loc.x < -width || loc.x > width || loc.y < -height || loc.y > height ) return touched;
    else
    {
        self.state = ACTIVE;
        self.action = MOVE_STOPPED;
        self.currPoint = self.prevPoint = self.avatar.position;
        touched = YES;
    }

//    CCLabelTTF *lbl = (CCLabelTTF *)[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag: -10] getChildByTag: 100];
//    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Touch Pos: (%.2f, %.2f)", [self.avatar boundingBox].size.width, [self.avatar boundingBox].size.height ];
//    [lbl setString: str];

    return touched;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% on this, but try to add this after converting to GL:

```
loc = [self.avatar convertToNodeSpace:loc];
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but convertToNodeSpace method did not work too. I already tried it prior to posting this question, as well as searching on google and raywenderlich.com forum. The code should work but it is not. Gone back and walked thru entire class that implements the movement controller but no luck.

Comment: NSLog is your best friend ;) ... did you try self.avatar when you tried converting to node space ?

Comment: Yes I tried logging location of touch (convertToGL), the Rect size of my sprite and they all matchup as it should, just not sure why the whole screen is giving off active state when I am touching no where near the sprite.